# TextView text going out of bounds

Tags: java, android, textview, height, autosize

I know this question had been asked a lot but I really searched for an hour and still haven't found the answer. My TextView in my dialog fragment goes out of bounds, as in the texts inside. 
[image]

The first textview was supposed to say "Adakah anda......." but it goes out of bounds just like that. I tried changing from wrap to match parent, then fill then weights but still won't change the problem, to autosize libraries (not what I wanted, I wanted to resize the textview, not textsize). Please help, tq.

Below is the  XML Code

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"


        android:layout_height = "match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id = "@+id/tvAdakah"
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:layout_weight = "1"
            android:text = "@string/adakah_anda_menstruasi_pada_hari_ini" />

        <Switch
            android:layout_width = "match_parent"
            android:layout_height = "match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is not enough , please put xml layout file of your dialog fragment

Comment: edited, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following,

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

for the textView, Maybe it can help

Answer (score 0):

You can show it in one line and make moving text

use xml code like this

```xml
 <TextView
      android:id = "@+id/tvAdakah"
      android:layout_width = "match_parent"
      android:layout_height = "match_parent"
      android:layout_weight = "1"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
      android:text = "@string/adakah_anda_menstruasi_pada_hari_ini" />
```

In java class you need to set selected this textView

```
TextView view = findViewById(R.id.tvAdakah);
view.setSelected(true);
```

hope it will helpful